# Is it possible to detect if there is unsaved changes on a react form?

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

Lets say I have multiple pages in my react-app, each one of these pages uses Form for it's inputs. I have to detect changes made if there was changes made on an input. I will then prompt a user with a custom modal (if the user tries to exit without saving changes) that they have unsaved changes.
I can try doing and 'onChange' on each input but that wont be the most efficient solution.

Is there a better way todo this?

Comment: Use a library like `react-hooks-form`

Comment: You could store the changes in local storage, that way the user doesn't lose progress if he exits the page, since most of them will still exit the page.

Comment: We use react hook form, as Konrad mentions also.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the unsaved changes in a useState boolean, React won't update this if the result will be the same. So having `onChange={() => setUnsavedChanges(true)}` on every text field won't be computationally expensive, though it does seem a little inelegant. Agree with comments about using a form library, though I can't suggest any that would have this functionality built-in.

Comment: I am going with this approach, but this does however have a fault, lets say the input contains "xyz", i remove that input and change it back to "xyz", it still detects it as a change but in fact the actual string is the exact same

Comment: This is the same behaviour as Google Docs, though I guess that autosaves so a bit less noticeable